# WordPress Search Error: ?s= in URL

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm doing a few stuff for this [humanitarian association](http:///http://pisad.org) and they asked me to add a search button on their navbar.

So far I came up with two solutions but none of them work. They both add "?s=" into the URL, thus redirecting to an empty URL.

Example: if you type "programme" in the search field, the URL will be: http://pisad.org/?s=programme. This is an empty URL and it should ultimately redirect to http://pisad.org/nos-programmes-inedits/ instead.

The first solution tried: search on navigation menu plugin: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-box-on-navigation-menu/

The second solution tried: adding this code to the navbar

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right search-form searchform" id="searchform" role="search" method="GET" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>" id="searchform">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher" name="s" id="s">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Rechercher</button>
      </form>
```

Any idea why it's like that?

Comment: did you added a search template for your search in your theme to display the results of your search ?

Comment: No. How should I proceed?

Comment: read https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: You have an `Error 500` when you load a page like `http://pisad.org/?s=programme`. Turn [debugging on](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and fix the issues.